# Proving/disproving a sentence using resolution refutation which doesn't consist of any single atoms

Tags: logic

I have to prove or disprove the statement

```
P → Q, Q → R : P → (Q ∧ R)
```

I have to use resolution refutation for this, so the left becomes ¬P ∨ Q, ¬Q ∨ R when converted to CNF and then the right can be negated, converted to CNF added to the left, resulting in me having to prove the sentence

```
{¬P ∨ Q, ¬Q ∨ R, P ∨ ¬Q, P ∨ ¬R}: ⊥
```

The issue here is that I'm not sure how to do this as I can't resolve 2 negations in one step, which would be necessary as none of the parts consist of single atoms. How should I go about proving/disproving this?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, no. You have the right method, but need to take things more carefully. Let us do it one step at a time:  $$\begin{split}
 P \to Q,&~& Q \to R &~&&: P \to (Q \wedge R) \quad& \text{Statement}\\
 P\to Q,&& Q\to R,&& \neg(P\to(Q\wedge R))&:\bot & \text{Negate the Consequent}\\ 
 \neg P\vee Q,&& \neg Q\vee R,&& \neg(P\to(Q\wedge R))&:\bot&\text{Implication Equivalence}\\ 
 \neg P\vee Q,&& \neg Q\vee R,&& P\wedge\neg(Q\wedge R))&:\bot &\text{Implication Negation}\\ 
 \neg P\vee Q,&& \neg Q\vee R,&& P\wedge(\neg Q\vee\neg R)&:\bot & \text{de Morgan's Rule}\\ 
 \neg P\vee Q,&& \neg Q\vee R,&& P, \neg Q\vee\neg R&:\bot & \text{Clauseation}\\ 
 \end{split}$$

You should now be able to readily resolve $\{ \{\neg P, Q\}, \{\neg Q, R\}, P, \{\neg Q,\neg R\}\}$ into a contradiction.